# Trouble shooting white screen - sony a7c

Tags: sony-alpha

Problem when shooting a computer or tablet screen

If any of you encountered this situation: When photographing a white screen of a computer, phone or tablet, it does not appear white and the light tends to turn red (red color) even if the temperature is locked or a profile picture, the same problem exists!
I will show you 2 videos explaining both problems

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jQ5jSXG_EQ_dtRrf3aGS5onsLuEMz-_g/view?fbclid=IwAR2D2scrOOi9Z9ftcB1XL5dFxhnAIxB8ZDtGaLISfo4bkH1Ct7htNVQj_jY

Is it possible to bea a global issue in Sony cameras?

[https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TS560x560~forums/65464637/3abd5b575d834c679dfd0dc4c4e1bd9f](https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/TS560x560%7Eforums/65464637/3abd5b575d834c679dfd0dc4c4e1bd9f)

https://vimeo.com/599840465

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but the white balance is drifting and it is not acting as if it is fixed... are you certain that it is?

E.g. in the first video, when the camera initially moves to the grey card I get Lab readings of 82.6, 3.6, 1.6 average; and just before it moves back to the ipad I get readings of 82, 0, -0... which means the camera's WB shifted during the time it was focused on the grey card. I noticed the same color drift as it was focused on the black BG and on the ipad, but I did not take those measurements.

A quick search shows that the WB is fixed to auto if the capture mode is set to intelligent auto.
The manual also states that in difficult situations (mercury/sodium lamps) where the camera does not achieve correct WB to use a custom WB setting. I would try that even if you are certain it is already using a fixed WB setting. If the color still drifts then I would have to say you have a faulty camera.

[image]

Comment: In the video you can see the white balance changing. Shoot in manual mode. Any setting that says "Intelligent" is suspect since the camera will do things it thinks is right.

Answer (score 0):

As you have colour temperature locked and it seems correct (based on the background and gray card) the problem for me it's no in the camera. You take photo/video of active light source and with high probability this screen is not calibrated. So the main reason for me is the colour of the light, emitted by the tablet/phone itself. You can try to calibrate these devices. Or just ignore it.

P.S. Based on comment seems like camera sensor is also involved (different sensitivity to different light waves). I have no suggestions in this direction.

Comment: But i tried shooting same scenes with same lighting with iphone or a canon 250D and no problems happened like the sony sensor did

Comment: @AhmedKamal, we talk about different sensors. So for sure camera itself is involved. :(

Comment: Is it possible when using a lens filter the problem will be solved?

Sorry, I don't know the language, I use Google Translate

Comment: @AhmedKamal, you can try CPL filter (polarizer) to filter, but this will reduce significantly the light from the screen

Comment: I draw on the iPad, and I did not face any problem with photography in Canon, but the problem is with Sony, if I do not find a solution to the problem, I will sell the camera

Comment: For the record, I tried the s log photography and the problem did not appear even after adding a lut